# Error implementing sass-loader webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, css-loader, sass-loader

I am currently trying to get sass working with my webpack application. I have had success with configuring `style-loader` & `css-loader`. However, when I try and implement `sass-loader` I receive the following error:

```
bundle.js:598 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "!!./../../css-loader/index.js!./../../sass-loader/index.js!./index.js?http:/localhost:8000"
```

Let me take you through the steps of how I installed `style-loader` & `css-loader`.

1. Ran `npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev`
2. Added loaders to webpack.config:

   ```
   module: {
     loaders: [
       {
         test: /\.jsx?$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'react-hot!babel'
       },
       {
         test: /\.css$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Created css folder and placed in there `myStyle.css`
4. Imported stylesheet into react component `require(../../css/myStyle.css`

This worked and I did not have any issues with it. After this I attempted to add `sass-loader`. The steps I took were very similar to the first.

1. Ran `npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`
2. Added loader to webpack.config

   ```
   module: {
     loaders: [
       {
         test: /\.jsx?$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'react-hot!babel'
       },
       {
         test: /\.css$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
       },
       {
         text: /\.scss$/,
         exlude: /node_modules/,
         loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Change `myStyle.css` to `myStyle.scss`.
4. Imported stylesheet into react component `require('../../myStyle.scss')`

After this I receive the error that is pasted above in the DOM. Here is the error that the console barfs at me:

```
[1] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 1.01 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
[3] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 7.15 kB {0} [built]
[4] (webpack)/hot/only-dev-server.js 981 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[6] ./src/index.jsx 2.42 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
[7] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 954 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[9] ./~/react-hot-loader/~/react-hot-api/modules/index.js 993 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[11] ./~/react-hot-loader/RootInstanceProvider.js 975 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[13] ./~/react/lib/ReactMount.js 966 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[15] ./~/react/react.js 930 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[18] ./~/react-hot-loader/makeExportsHot.js 957 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/index.jsx
Module build failed: 
import React from 'react';
^
  Invalid CSS after "i": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "import React from '"
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/src/index.jsx (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./src/index.jsx 8:14-115 17:2-21:4 18:20-121

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!(webpack)-dev-server/client?      http:/localhost:8000
Module build failed: 
var url = require('url');
^
  Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var url = require('"
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js (line 1, column 1)
@ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 4:14-115 13:2-17:4 14:20-121

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!(webpack)/hot/only-dev-server.js
Module build failed: 
var lastData;
^
  Property "var" must be followed by a ':'
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/node_modules/webpack/hot/only-dev-server.js (line 7, column 2)
 @ (webpack)/hot/only-dev-server.js 4:14-104 13:2-17:4 14:20-110

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/react-hot-   loader/RootInstanceProvider.js
Module build failed: 
'use strict';
^
  Invalid CSS after "'": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "'use strict';"
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/node_modules/react-hot-loader/RootInstanceProvider.js (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./~/react-hot-loader/RootInstanceProvider.js 4:14-103 13:2-17:4 14:20-109

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!(webpack)/buildin/module.js
Module build failed: 
module.exports = function(module) {
         ^
  Invalid CSS after "module.exports": expected "{", was "= function(module) "
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js (line 1, column 15)
@ (webpack)/buildin/module.js 4:14-95 13:2-17:4 14:20-101

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/react-hot-loader/makeExportsHot.js
Module build failed: 
'use strict';
^
  Invalid CSS after "'": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "'use strict';"
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/node_modules/react-hot-loader/makeExportsHot.js (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./~/react-hot-loader/makeExportsHot.js 4:14-97 13:2-17:4 14:20-103

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/react/lib/ReactMount.js
Module build failed: 
 */
  ^
  Invalid CSS after " */": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "'use strict';"
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js (line 10, column 4)
 @ ./~/react/lib/ReactMount.js 4:14-99 13:2-17:4 14:20-105

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/react-hot-loader/~/react-hot-api/modules/index.js
Module build failed: 
'use strict';
^
  Invalid CSS after "'": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "'use strict';"
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/node_modules/react-hot-loader/node_modules/react-hot-api/modules/index.js (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./~/react-hot-loader/~/react-hot-api/modules/index.js 4:14-106 13:2-17:4 14:20-112

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/react/react.js
Module build failed: 
'use strict';
^ 
  Invalid CSS after "'": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "'use strict';"
  in /Users/tsiebenhaar/Sites/extendedFamily-frontend/node_modules/react/react.js (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./~/react/react.js 4:14-88 13:2-17:4 14:20-94
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. For now I am off to bed and will be checking back tomorrow morning. Happy coding to all and to all a good night!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to load a jsx file (in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!**./src/index.jsx**) instead of a css/scss/sass file.